# mp4 video playback is horrible

Tags: video-player, mp4

How can I get mp4 video to playback normal. They skip and look horrible. I was able to get them to playback on Fedora using a different setting with smplayer but nothing seems to work with Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried the application called VLC? It is available from the Ubuntu Software centre.

Comment: Yeah, I tried VLC and played with settings A LOT and nothing worked out. When I got it to work on Fedora all I had to do was set H.264 codec to skip always.

Comment: Can you give us a better idea about your machine specs, specifically cpu and graphics? It's possible you might be able to enable hardware acceleration.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.

Comment: Graphic card or RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Playback of cpu intensive video can be problematic if your CPU is not fast enough.

Smplayer is a frontend for mplayer.
You can install mplayer and start the playback from the console. Reading the console output is mostly very helpful. You can change the output driver.
Changing you Graphics-driver can also sometimes solve the problem.

Comment: Ahh, somewhere to start I gues. Says my cpu is to slow and a lot of other stuff. Looks like I'll have some fun.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem, too. I came to [the conclusion](https://askubuntu.com/a/180541/19753) that `gxine` was best for this. (`smplayer` kept delaying the video further and further.)

Answer (score -1):

ffplay it from a command line, although I have some issues with the subtitles.
You can try puppy linux, no lags and it works fine with the Gnome player, except that you may have the HDMI audio issues... VLC did not solve it for me either...